# consume web service which accept three classes as entry

Tags: c#, web-services, rest

i want to consume the web service which accept three classes as entry parameters. i have this method for creating a request and response:

```
private T SendDataToServer<T>(string endpoint, string method, T pun)
{
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(endpoint);
    request.Accept = "application/json";
    request.ContentType = "application/json";
    request.Method = method;
    var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
    var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
    serializer.WriteObject(requestStream, pun);
    requestStream.Close();
    var response = request.GetResponse();
    if (response.ContentLength == 0)
    {
        response.Close();
        return default(T);
    }
    var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    var responseObject = (T)serializer.ReadObject(responseStream);
    responseStream.Close();
    return responseObject;
}
```

this work just fine. but this method just work with one class. how can send three classes to the web service?
thank you

Comment: Make an object out of those three classes and send them as a serialized JSON to the service.